# Camera Icon Disappears

Tags: java, android, xml

I m Making business card reader app,user click on camera icon to scan after clicking camera icon gets invisible and it make shutter sound ,if cards are scanned continuously Camera icon doesn't show i.e., it is disappeared .

Camerafragment.java

```
 mCapture = view.findViewById(R.id.capture); 

    if (mCapture != null) {
        mCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                disableSensors=true;

                if(isManualMode&&totalCardCount==0){

                    card_pack_exhausted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    takePhoto();
                }

            }

        });
    }

    public void takePhoto() {

    mCapture.setEnabled(false);
    mCapture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    cameraPreview.takePicture();
}
```

cameraPreview.java

```
 public void takePicture() { 

    if (hasAutoFocus) {
        if (focusMode == FocusMode.TOUCH) {
            if (focused && tapArea != null) {
                focused();
            } else {
                startFocusing();
            }
        }
    } else {
        focused();
    }
}
 private void focused() {
    focusing = false;

    String checkBeep =  Prefs.getString("BeepDone","");
if (!checkBeep.equals("true")) {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer2, mMediaPlayer;
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(WebServiceSingleTon.getInstance().mainActivity, R.raw.beepnew);
   mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    Prefs.putString("BeepDone", "true");
 }  
if (focusCallback != null) {
    focusCallback.onFocused(camera);
}}
```

Comment: What do you think `mCapture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` will do?

Comment: after clicking image camera icon will Invisible n for next time scanning it  will be Visible ,but after continuously scanning camera icon wont be visible. I tired Making Camera icon Visible all the time but it get static i.e., doesn't perform action.